# Roots of bi-quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

I got an question to find the product of the roots of $x^2 + 18x + 30 = 2\sqrt{x^2 + 18x + 45}$. This is what I did: 
 $y = x^2 + 18x$. So $y + 30 = 2\sqrt{y + 45}$.

Squaring it on both sides:

$(y + 30)^2 = (2\sqrt{y + 45})^2\Rightarrow y^2 + 30^2 + 60y = 4(y + 45)\Rightarrow y^2 + 900 + 60y - 4y - 180 = 0\Rightarrow y^2 + 720 + 56y = 0$.

Then using quadratic formula I got the values of $y$ as $-20$ and $-36$. Now plugging In the values as $x^2 + 18x + 36/+20 = 0$, I don't get a whole number as the value for $x$. This is the place I'm stuck.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Stuck? Why? Your equation has no integer solutions.

Comment: I mean I don't know how to find the product of the roots after that step

Comment: If $f(x)$ is any polynomial at all, what is the product of its roots? If you aren't familiar with Vieta's formulas, just think about a factorization of $f(x) = \prod (x-a_i)$ where the $a_i$ are the roots. What is $\prod a_i$ in terms of the coefficients of $f$?

Comment: Product of solutions is $(-9+\sqrt{61})(-9-\sqrt{61})=81-61=20$
The other equation gives solutions which are not actual solutions of the given equation. They come from the squaring and are extraneous (how do you call them ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product of the (real or complex) roots of $x^2+18x+36$ is $36$, the product of those of $x^2+18x+20$ is $20$, hence the product of the roots of
$(x^2+18x+36)(x^2+18x+20)$ is $720$.

There would remain to eliminate the roots which do not belong to the domain of validity of the initial equation, the roots of which must satisfy:
$$x^2+18x+30\ge0.$$

Comment: Thanks. But what if they tell to find the roots of the equation...

Comment: Clearly the condition is satisfied only by the roots of $x^2+18x+20=0$. For the first quadratic equation, $x^2+18x+30=-6$.