# Solving $x^2 + 18x + 30 = 2 \sqrt{x^2 + 18x + 45}$? (1983 AIME problem 3)

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, quadratics, substitution, quartics

> What is the product of the real roots of the equation $x^2 + 18x + 30 = 2 \sqrt{x^2 + 18x + 45}$?

I know it is a messy/bad idea, but I first started off by squaring both sides and moving everything to one side to get $$x^4 + 36x^3 + 384x^2 + 1080x + 900 - 4x^2 - 72x - 180 = x^4 + 36x^3 + 380x^2 + 1008x + 720 .$$ 
And by (generalisation) of Vieta's formula, the product of the real roots should be $\frac{720}{1} = 720$, but that is wrong, and I don't understand why.

Comment: This is the product of all the roots not only of the real ones

Comment: How do you know that the real solutions after squaring soddisfy $x^2+18x+45>0$? You should exclude the ones who doesn't

Comment: Just solve $z=2\sqrt{z+15}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Roots of bi-quadratic equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509332/roots-of-bi-quadratic-equation)

Answer (score 5):

Use the following substitution.  $$x^2+18x+45=t$$ and we obtain
$$t-2\sqrt{t}-15=0$$ ot
$$(\sqrt{t}-1)^2=16$$ and since $\sqrt{t}\geq0$, we obtain $$\sqrt{t}=5,$$
$$x^2+18x+20=0$$ or
$$(x+9)^2=61$$ and we get the answer:
$$\{-9\pm\sqrt{61}\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $t=x^2+18x +30$, then we get $$t^2=4t+60$$ so $(t-10)(t+6)=0$ and thus

1. case $x^2+18x+36=0$ so $x_1=x_2=-6$ which is impossible (left side is negative)
2. case $x^2+18x+20=0$ **so the product of real roots is $20.$**

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2 + 18x + 30 = 2 \sqrt{x^2 + 18x + 45}$$
let $x^2+18x+30=u$
so
$$u= 2 \sqrt{u+15}$$
$$u^2=4(u+15)$$
$$u^2-4u-60=0$$
$$(u+6)(u-10)=0$$
so
$$({\color{Red} {x^2+18x+36}})({\color{Blue} {x^2+18x+20}})=0$$
the roots of $({\color{Red} {x^2+18x+36}})$ do not satisfy the original equation especially in the term $\sqrt{x^2 + 18x + 45}$ so the product of real roots will be $20$

Comment: there are some contrain on the radical